# Newly built system wont boot

Tags: bios, computer-building

I am having a problem with assembling a new desktop, this is not new to me but the problem is.

When I turn it on all I get is a black screen, other than displaying in the bottom is the number `99`

I have tried disconnecting various hardware but it still happens.

There are no beeps when I turn it on.

I can't tell you the exact specs at the moment because I do not have the packing form.

Comment: Are you getting any beeps during startup? Do you get a BIOS screen at all? Are you using onboard graphics or a video card? You can also try the quick obvious stuff, such as reseating memory, reseating processor, and checking to make sure your video card is firmly seated in the correct slot.

Comment: no beeps, no bios, only in the bottom right corner it is displaying 99.
it has no external GPU

Comment: Sorry to ask, but please confirm the PSU and CPU fans are spinning.

Comment: They both are, i'm going to try another PSU as Garry Morris sugested and see if that helps, else i'm sending the mobo back

Answer (score 0):

I had this code before when i had a motherboard that was DOA. It turned out to be some sort of electrical/shorting fault on the motherboard. I would guess it's either that, or a power problem.

Do you have another PSU you could test it with? Is the board mounted correctly on motherboard 'riser' screws? I feel this one miight end up as an RMA.

Comment: i will try that out then